# What is the best practice to track local database changes for deploy on live database?

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core

what is the best practice to track database changes?

**for example**

- When we add a new column in table
- change the column data type and so on..

so I forget what I changed and it becomes a problem for live database when I deploy the project
because I can't replace the database

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can create a Database Project that will allow putting version control on the database, deploy small incremental changes, and also help with renaming objects that are referenced elsewhere